# bash: We determine whether the computer belongs to the active directory group and, depending on this, perform the action

Tags: linux, bash

It is necessary to distribute the automatic shutdown task to all client machines running Linux, except for a certain group of Active Directory computers pan-sgg-dalas. The closest thing I found is below in the code, but it's doesn't working.

```
echo "set time, except group pan-sgg-dalas"
computer_name=$(hostname -s)

if getent group pan-sgg-dalas | grep -q "$computer_name"; then
    echo "0 22 * * * root /sbin/shutdown -h now" > /etc/cron.d/shutdown_22:00
    echo "set time 22:00"
else
    echo "Computer belong to group pan-sgg-dalas."
fi
```

Code doesn't work properly. And I can't find error.

Comment: Whether `getent group` works at all here depends on how your NSS integration is configured, how you defined the groups in LDAP, etc. We can't possibly know if this is expected to work or not based only on the content in the script itself.

Comment: What part of it isn't working correctly? If you run the individual commands by hand, do they get the expected results? If not, you should ask about those commands on [unix.se].

Comment: _If you personally own and control_ the NSS/LDAP configuration, you could decide to map the relevant AD/LDAP groups into UNIX groups and use traditional tools like `getent`; _or_ you could decide to use `ldapsearch` and similar to directly query the directory service; but you, as someone familiar with how your directory infrastructure is set up, need to make that decision; we can't make it for you. (Often, your sysadmin team or AD administrator will be the people you want to reach out to for help here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy getent group works. When i enter it in terminal i take computers name, which joined in that group.

Comment: @Barmar i think isn't correctly part `grep -q "$computer_name"`

Comment: `set -x` is your friend for showing the value of `computer_name` -- if it's got whitespace that isn't there in the getent output that could be your problem.

Comment: You might also want to do a similar inspection of the `getent group` output. If you ran, say, `group_members=$(getent group pan-sgg-dalas)` and then added `declare -p computer_name group_members >&2` to your script, that would make the script's output have enough details that someone else who isn't you could run `printf '%s\n' "$group_members" | grep -q "$computer_name"` and get the same results you have here.

Comment: (because really, the biggest issue with this question right now is that as it was originally asked, nobody but you can test proposed answers)

Comment: Note that this use of `grep` may not be safe. If your computer name is `abc`, and the computer `xabcy` is in the group, your grep will be successful. You should use `grep -w` so it matches whole words.

Comment: i just need set that code in startup script. and when computer run, that he must detect, is  his hostname belongs group pan-sgg-dalas or not. If not he must set time shutdown in 22:00.

Comment: @looks like truth. When i'll go on work, i try use `grep -w`

Comment: To be clear, `grep -w` would stop this from saying your computer is in the group when it isn't, but I understand the problem this question is about to be the opposite of that -- grep saying the computer _isn't_ in the group when it is. You _do_ want `grep -w`, but I'm not at all convinced that it's the whole of the issue at hand; again, to be able to propose a solution with any confidence we'd really want specific examples of the output of the various commands, emitted in such a way that things like whitespace, nonprinting characters, &c are shown.

Comment: You should probably also use the `-F` option.  It is possible that you want or need `-i`, too.  Overall, `grep -Fw -q` or maybe `grep -Fwi -q`.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ -https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that i had, when i enter  `declare -- computer_name="ws-pa-sius-l002"
declare -- group_members="pan-sgg-dalas:*:1941423615:ws-pa-test-l001\$,ws-pa-jeu-l004\$,ws-pa-ukg-ktr\$,ws-pa-arm-kszi\$,ws-pa-ds-dis1\$,ws-pa-ds-dis2\$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've shared the content of your data, we know that `group_members` looks like `pan-sgg-dalas:*:1941423615:ws-pa-test-l001$,ws-pa-jeu-l004$,ws-pa-ukg-ktr$,ws-pa-arm-kszi$,ws-pa-ds-dis1$,ws-pa-ds-dis2$`

There are a few things here: First, we should be taking only the fourth column; second, we need to split by commas and remove the trailing `$`s to get something suitable for an exact-match comparison. So, let's do that:

```
# output of actual commands hardcoded to allow reproducibility
computer_name=ws-pa-sius-l002
group_members='pan-sgg-dalas:*:1941423615:ws-pa-test-l001$,ws-pa-jeu-l004$,ws-pa-ukg-ktr$,ws-pa-arm-kszi$,ws-pa-ds-dis1$,ws-pa-ds-dis2$'

group_members=${group_members##*:} # remove everything up to the last : in group_members

if [[ ",$group_members" = *,"$computer_name"$ ]]; then
  echo "$computer_name is a group member" >&2
else
  echo "$computer_name is NOT a group member" >&2
fi
```

When running that we get `ws-pa-sius-l002 is NOT a group member` as output -- but that's correct! `ws-pa-sius-l002` is indeed not in the list stored in `group_members` in the sample data given.

By the way -- note how we're prefixing a `,` to the `$group_members` string when checking whether `,${computer_name}$` is inside that string; the `,` on the front and the `$` on the end prevents partial or incomplete matches from falsely claiming a host to be present when something with a longer name incorporating that short name as a subset is actually present instead.